# Show that $(\lambda A+B)^{-1}B=1-\lambda\left((\lambda A+B)^{-1}A\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A,B\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ and suppose there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ such that $\lambda A+B$ invertible. How does one deduce that:

$$(\lambda A+B)^{-1}B=1-\lambda\left((\lambda A+B)^{-1}A\right)?$$

I feel that this should be quite easy, and no doubt it is - my apprehension is that $(\lambda A+B)^{-1}$ need not have an immediately obvious form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Begin with the simple observation that

$B = (\lambda A + B) - \lambda A \tag 1$

and, exploiting the given hypothesis that $\lambda A + B$ is invertible, multiply through by $(\lambda A + B)^{-1}$:

$(\lambda A + B)^{-1}B$
$= (\lambda A + B)^{-1} (\lambda A + B) - (\lambda A + B)^{-1} \lambda A$
$= I - \lambda ((\lambda A + B)^{-1} A),   \tag 2$

thus obtaining the requisite result.

Comment: Yes, I like the way of thinking here - there is reason yet!

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames:  thank you for the kind words; I tried to present the most straightforward derivation I could.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$$(\lambda A+B)^{-1}B=I-\lambda\left((\lambda A+B)^{-1}A\right)$$
$$\iff(\lambda A+B)^{-1}B+\lambda\left((\lambda A+B)^{-1}A\right)=I$$
$$\iff(\lambda A+B)^{-1}(B+\lambda A)=I$$
which is true simce $\lambda A+B$ was presumed invertible.

Comment: Ugh, I feel so dumb - of course!